# How to access chrome profiling programmatically

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, profiling, google-chrome-devtools

Looking for some chrome API (to be used in chrome extension) that let me to do following programmatically:-
- start profiling
- end profiling
- get list of time taken by all JS on the page

I can achieve the same in Firefox as:

```
jsd = DebuggerService.getService(jsdIDebuggerService)
// start the profiling as
jsd.flags |= COLLECT_PROFILE_DATA;

// stop the profilinf as
jsd.flags &= ~COLLECT_PROFILE_DATA;

// get the details of how much time each JS function took
jsd.enumerateScripts({enumerateScript: function(script)
{
// script object has timings detail
}
```

Even some API that can let me to export the profiling info from developer tool bar will be helpful

Answer (score 14):

You can profile a script in google chrome programmatically using the following code

```
console.profile("MyProfile");
// Enter name of script here
console.profileEnd();
```

"MyProfile" is the name of the profile which will be created.

Source:

http://blog.codestars.eu/2011/profiling-with-webkit/

You could get the time for a function / code snippet to execute by using a combination of `console.time()`and `console.timeEnd()`

Comment: I can start/stop the profiler this way but what about fetching the profiling data programatically i.e. which JS function what amount of time.

Comment: You could get the time for a function / code snippet to execute by using a combination of `console.time()`and `console.timeEnd()` Answer updated accordingly

Comment: I think he want his extension to profile the js functions on the page, not his own functions.

Comment: thanks  Sebastián for clarification. I want to profile the JS on the web page opened, not of my own function.

Comment: After console.profileEnd(); you can get to the data by either going to the profile tab in your developer tool or programmatically by using the command console.profiles();

Comment: console.profiles() doesn't appear to actually exist?